# Select Every Node in Kendo TreeView

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have a kendo treeview like this:

```
sectionTreeView.kendoTreeView({
        dataValueField: "Id",
        dataTextField: "Name",
        checkboxes: {
            checkChildren: true
        }
});
```

I use the following code to programmatically select the root node:

```
divTreeView.getKendoTreeView().select(".k-item:first");
```

However, the first node is only highlighted but its checkbox remains unchecked and so is every child node below it. How do I make every checkbox checked?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the checkbox after you have selected the node like this:

```
var treeView = divTreeView.getKendoTreeView();
// you need to select the node for this to work
treeView.select(".k-item:first");
treeView.select().find(".k-checkbox input").prop("checked", true).change();
```

Comment: Its working fine. Tried lot of things...but this helped me out. 
thank you boniestlawyer..

Answer (score 0):

$("#accountsTree .k-item input[type=checkbox]").attr('checked', 'checked');

Comment: Can you please add a description of some sort to your one-liner?